# How to extract the text from a string - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have about 670k products I need to categorise before uploading. Obviously this is too many to do manually.

So if say column C is Product Title, and in Row 3 one of the words (there will be 10-12 words and they will be in different orders) is 'Example' then I want in say column F (product category) it to have 'Example'.

Is there a way to do this? I've been looking and so far can only find numerical examples, and when I've tried they don't work with words. I assume, if it can be done, I'll have to copy down a full column of a formula but that's fine as I can delete it when done.

Comment: perhaps `=if(isnumber(search("example", c3)), "example", text(,))` ...?

Answer (score 0):

If there's any identifier which separates the `Product Category` and the remaining digits like `"-"`, you can use the following formula in `Column F`,

```
=LEFT(C2,SEARCH("-",C2)-1)
```

If there's no separator, and if there's a constant number of digits after `Category`, say `'5'` then use

```
=LEFT(C2,LEN(C2)-5)
```

If not both, mention some of the data(sample) to help you more.